# My JLabel doesn't display my images from camera

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jlabel

I've created a GUI for an app that uses my laptop camera, when i press record i can record a video from it but i want to display also what my camera is seeing. So, my problem is that my label does not display in the loop the image from camera. After the loop is done and the record finished it displays my last image.

```
void startInregistrare() throws InterruptedException
    {

        File saveFile=new File("saved.mp4");
        IMediaWriter writer=ToolFactory.makeWriter(saveFile.getName());
        Dimension size=WebcamResolution.VGA.getSize();
        writer.addVideoStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_H264,size.width,size.height);
        long start=System.currentTimeMillis();
        Webcam cameraWeb=openWebcam(size);
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {

            BufferedImage image=ConverterFactory.convertToType(cameraWeb.getImage(),BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
            IConverter converter=ConverterFactory.createConverter(image, IPixelFormat.Type.YUV420P);
            IVideoPicture frame1=converter.toPicture(image,(System.currentTimeMillis()-start)*1000);
            frame1.setKeyFrame(i==0);
            frame1.setQuality(100);
            writer.encodeVideo(0, frame1);
            Thread.sleep(20);
            lblLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));

        }
        writer.close();
        System.out.println("Finished recording");
        cameraWeb.close();
    }
```

Comment: Start by taking a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).  I would suggest that the solution to your problem would be to make use of a [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) to extract each frame and then send that, via the `process`/`publish` methods, to the Event Dispatching Thread, so you can update the label safely

Comment: @MadProgrammer can you give me a hint? I've tried and it does not work...